# How to solve blob undefined issue in vuejs

Tags: vuejs2, blob

I am using **var blob = new Blob(...)** to convert octet stream to image, but I get an error Blob is not defined, there's anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Did u include Blob shim?

Comment: show your code, then only we can help :)

Comment: I had forgotten to include Blob shim. Thanks @AliaksandrPitkevich

Comment: How does one include Blob shim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include [Blob shim](https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js/blob/master/Blob.js)

See also [Blob MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)